# Graph Connectedness Proof

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, graph-connectivity

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph. Assume that $G$ is bipartite, connected, and each vertex of $G$ has degree $2016$. Let $v \in V$ and $H = (V - v, E - \{e \in E: v \in e\}).$ Show that the graph $H$ is connected.

I think it's a little bit complicated. It would be helpful to count up vertices in $G$.

Comment: What does it exactly mean to have a "degree in 2016?" Does it mean for each vertex $v \in V, deg(v) = 2016$?

Comment: @Gogis Yes, it is that.

Comment: @S.Michal what is definition of consistent graph?

Comment: When for each partition of a set $V$ into two parts $A$ and $B$ exsists an egde $xy$ in graph $G$ such as $x ∈ A, y ∈ B$.

Comment: @S.Michal, that suggests that you're talking about a *connected* graph.